# How apply a bitmask to an integer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, integer

Here is the problem:

The database Rx30 stores the status of a prescription in a field called 'Rxstatus.' The number they store there is an integer that is never higher than 255. The bits that are set determine whether or not a script is filled.

A representative told us that if 16, 32, or 128 is set, the script is deemed 'unfilled.'

So now what we need to do is take an integer, say '49', and see which bits are set. This needs to be done through MySQL for speed's sake. I understand that 49 is:

```
32+16+1 = 49
```

So 16 is set in this field, therefore the script is unfilled.

How (in MySQL) can I take an integer, say 152 for example, and determine which bits of it are set?

Once we determine what's set, if 16, 32, or 128 is set we can deem the script unfilled and produce the correct results.

Comment: you probably mean converted from a byte, since a bit cannot even be higher than 1 :)

Comment: Yes I do, sorry about that!

Comment: What you're talking about is a common structure called a bit mask.

Comment: You can use the [Bit functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) of MySQL, i.e bitwise AND with 16 or 32 or 128.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reviewing some of the answers here and discussing with some coworkers, we got the correct result by checking the length after the conversion:

```
LENGTH( CONV( Rxstatus, 10, 2 ) ) NOT IN ( 5, 6, 8 ))
```

For example, we use the length of the field to determine if the number was set. If 5, 6, or 8 are set in the field, then 16, 32, or 128 MUST exist.

```
10000    (Length 5, = 16)
100000   (Length 6, = 32)
10000000 (Length 8, = 128)
```

Just the length itself gives us the values that must be set. Thank you guys for all of your help in solving this problem in just 30 minutes!

Over 460,000 fields the query ran in 0.23 seconds. :D

Comment: This is a fragile approach. Specifically, if bit 7 is set, then length will be 7. So your test will return false. **Unfortunately**, if bit 7 is set, it will return false even if bit 6 is *also* set - in which case it should be returning true. Anyone reading this should instead use one of the "bit masking" answers, that show how to use "&" to extract/test the desired bits.

Answer (score 12):

If you have a test bit mask, e.g. `32+16+1 = 49`, and you want to know if *any* of these are set in `Rxstatus`, you use:

```
SELECT Rxstatus & 49 != 0
```

If you want to know if *all* of them are set, you use:

```
SELECT Rxstatus & 49 = 49
```

To set all the bits from the bitmask, you do:

```
UPDATE Rx30
SET Rxstatus = Rxstatus | 49
WHERE <condition>
```

To unset all the bits from the bitmask, you do:

```
UPDATE Rx30
SET Rxstatus = Rxstatus & ~49
WHERE <condition>
```

Comment: To clarify for the specific question asked:  OP asks how to know if any of "16, 32, or 128" is set. The sum of those is "176", so the solution for him would be `SELECT Rxstatus & 176 != 0`.  OR to make it easier to see the bits being tested, provide the test value in binary:  `SELECT Rxstatus & b'10110000' != 0`.

Comment: ... Or if you prefer working with decimal representations of bit values: `SELECT Rxstatus & (128|32|16) != 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [MySQL BIT functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html) like `&`

```
select Rxstatus & 2 = 2 as 2_set, 
       Rxstatus & 4 = 4 as 4_set,
       Rxstatus & 8 = 8 as 8_set,
       Rxstatus & 16 = 16 as 16_set,
       Rxstatus & 32 = 32 as 32_set,
       Rxstatus & 64 = 64 as 64_set,
       Rxstatus & 128 = 128 as 128_set
from your_table
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/38043)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to binary, this way you can see what bits are set.

To do so you can use the [CONV() function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-conv-function.php), as an example, you can convert your number 49, from decimal to binary like this:

```
SELECT CONV(49,10,2);
```

resulting in `110001`

Comment: Future readers: Don't use `CONV`. After looking at the (fragile) accepted answer, I see that using `CONV` is a mistake. Because the length of the returned string will vary, depending on the number - so it is difficult to locate specific bits. Use bit masking instead - see other answers above.

Comment: Why would it be difficult? If you want to know the 4th bit and your string has length 3 it just means that it is 0

Comment: It is difficult *because the string length will vary depending on the size of the value*.  Consider values ranging from 0 to 255.  CONV will return strings ranging in length from 1 to 8.  Now, write a simple formula that will test for the bit with value 16. Its a mess - you have to handle 8 different string lengths. Possible, but not practical. (Its also inefficient, as you are converting a number to a string, and then extracting a character from the string. But that is not as important an issue.) Now try to test for multiple bits. Compare to top-rated approach: `SELECT Rxstatus & 176 != 0`.